# Cannot find script file in Angular CLI

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-cli

I am trying to use magicscroller to create a card layout carousel. 
So I have both the .css and .js of magicscroller referenced in my app.
The css file works fine, but the .js file is not found.

I get this error message in the chrome debugger: 
GET http://localhost:4200/magicscroll.js net::ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)

This is my folder structure:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/z6dXg.jpg

I have tried referencing the .js file in angular.json and index.html (it is inside the src folder).

angular.json:

```
"scripts": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
    "node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js",
    "magicscroll/magicscroll.js"
],
```

index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="magicscroll.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="magicscroll/magicscroll.js"></script>        
<script type="text/javascript" src="./magicscroll/magicscroll.js"></script>
```

Comment: Are you sure you provided the right path to magicscroll?  Did you try `"./magicscroll/magicscroll.js"` in angular.json? 
If you installed it with npm it should rather be in node modules

Comment: You may want to take a look at this: https://greensock.com/forums/topic/16825-good-way-to-install-gsap-scrollmagic-animation-plugin-to-angular-24/

Comment: I did not install it with npm, but I did try the "./magicsroll..." option

Comment: I suppose it's not working because you didn't install with npm, try doing it according directions

Comment: They did not publish it to npm, the link is about something different than what I am using. What I am using is magicscroll but the link is about scrollmagic.